# Is there a way to get an R Markdown document from a recently knitted document (html, pdf or Word)?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

So I just recently started to learn how to use RStudio for my Bio class. For my latest submission, I knitted my lab, which was made as an R Markdown, into an HTML file. For some reason, I might have deleted my RMD file, which was also needed in the submission. Is there any way to convert my HTML (PDF or even Word) file back into an R Markdown file?
Thank you so much!

-SuperEli

Comment: Only if you are using the R Markdown Notebook format, which generates a `.nb.html` file. You could restore the Rmd from that file. For other types of output files, you can't get the complete Rmd back. If all of your code is shown in the output document, you may copy and paste them back to a new Rmd, but you will certainly lose chunk options.

Answer (score 1):

No, one rmarkdown file generates a unique word/html/pdf
however, different rmarkdown files may generate same output results.